# Not able to find JRE in Select Bundle option in Install4J

Tags: java, install4j

I have recently created a java application.I am creating .exe file using install4J and I am planning to bundle the JRE along with the files so that the user can install it.

I have downloaded a JRE from the media section in install4J but I am not able to see the downloaded JRE in the options. It's asking me to choose one and I clicked manual selection which was the only option in the tab.

Why am I not able to find the JRE which I downloaded from install4J itself?

I am able to find the downloaded JREs in the computer but they are not appearing in the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the media wizard, you can only see JRE bundles that are applicable for the current media file. For example, for Windows 64-bit you have to download a 64-bit bundle, for Windows 32-bit a Windows 32-bit bundle.

Comment: So, I should be downloading (x86) JRE files. right?

Comment: Depends on the 64-bit setting in your Windows media file

Comment: Is there any way by which I can modify those settings?

Comment: What settings do you want to modify? The displayed list of JREs in the media wizard shows the applicable JREs for the selected platform.

Comment: Modify some settings so that I can use the existing JREs in install4J.

Comment: No, the JRE has to match the selected platform, you cannot change that and it would not make any sense to do so.

Comment: Okay. But I didn't select 64 or 32 bit in install4J. I just selected windows.

Comment: In the Windows media wizard, go to the "32-bit or 64-bit" step to select the platform.